# What are such illustrations called? How are they made?

Tags: illustration, style-identification

What are such illustrations called? How can they be made?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called Flat Art or the Flat Look. There is no automatic way to make it, it's drawn by hand in a vector graphics program like Illustrator.

The look is defined by basic geometric shapes like circles and squares. There is no shadow, transparency, gradient or outline used, only solid color blocks.

Comment: I would say that there is shadow in the sense that some blocks are colored in a darker shade than others to convey depth.